# Weird behaviour for my CNN validation accuracy and loss function during training phase

Tags: python, tensorflow, validation, keras, training-data

Here is the architecture of my network :

```
cnn3 = Sequential()
cnn3.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
cnn3.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
cnn3.add(Dropout(0.25))
cnn3.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
cnn3.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
cnn3.add(Dropout(0.25))
cnn3.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
cnn3.add(Dropout(0.2))
cnn3.add(Flatten())
cnn3.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
cnn3.add(Dropout(0.4)) # 0.3
cnn3.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
cnn3.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

When I have plotted both training and validation accuracies and loss functions I got the next two figures:

I could not understand why both validation accuracy and loss are not following training accuracy and loss ?

[image: LOSS]

[image: accuracy]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your validation is following the train loss and accuracy. There is just more jitter in the validation lines due to being a smaller data set. The offset between train and validation might be du to some degree of overfitting.

Comment: So it is possible to detect overfitting based on accuracy value of training and validation sets? So should I increase the validation dataset?

Comment: Yes, usually you detect overfitting by having a good train performance and a bad (or less good) validation performance. 
Increasing the validation set size will make the jitter less volatile, but it also means a smaller train set size...

Comment: well I am using Imagegenration for data augmentation will this resolve the probem?

Comment: You can definitely try it